# config server - non working samples, inadequate documentation

Tags: cloud, config

I am very keen on the config server + eureka for externalizing configuration & service discovery; among others.

The configserver in git (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver) is unusable b/c the snapshot (1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) imports do not exists. After searching the snapshot & mileston maven repos, I did find version 1.0.0.M3 for spring-cloud-starter-parent but now am getting an error in ConfigServerApplication b/c the org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient import is invalid.

I've thrashed around with code from the various 'sample' git projects over the course of several weeks. I've viewed numerous recorded session that I could find, read blogs and "documentation".

I realize that this effort is in progress. I also realize that the authors & many w/i the community are gurus; I am not.

For those of us who are mortal, is there any way we could ask you to create a course of study (w/ WORKING examples) that would allow us to sequentially learn this material (including the configuration)?

I'm seeing that the benefits of 'simplicity' (configuration does 'stuff' behind the scenes ... the "magic"), the learning curve for newcomers keeps growing.

So, in short, the general question is "how does someone new to the 'cloud' learn & be able to use this stuff?"